# Drawer button and title outside Drawer navigator in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to learn some react native basics and some navigation things. Below one of my screen with both Tab Navigator and Drawer Navigator together.

[image]

Here is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import AppRoot from '../pages/AppRoot';
import Profile from '../pages/Profile';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import LoginPage from '../pages/LoginPage';
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="AppRoot"
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#4B1E19'}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="New AppRoot" component={AppRoot} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'New Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile2"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile2',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

// Create your Drawer Navigator
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#4B1E19" barStyle="light-content" />
      <View style={styles.topBar}></View>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={LoginPage} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#4B1E19',
    height: 100,
    elevation: 5, // Increase elevation for a more pronounced shadow effect
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 5},
    shadowOpacity: 1, // Increase opacity for a darker shadow
    shadowRadius: 10, // Increase radius for a larger shadow
  },
});
```

But the requirement is to have that title and drawer toggling button to be outside the Drawer Navigator and I am really looking for placing that button inside this view

```
<View style={styles.topBar}></View>
```

But no idea how to add that custom button and title outside the drawer navigator. but functionally I am expecting the same way the button and title. Means whenever the screens switches the titles needs to change. Please help

Comment: Check https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/